# Bootstrap - my positioning with col doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make positions to my dis by col-md-x. I tryed, but my code doesn't react:

```
<div class="span9">
    <div class="well np">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">Text</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Text</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Text</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Text</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to be two divs next to each other, and next two below. 
It should work but doesn't... why col-md-6 don't want to work??

Comment: cause you are exceeding bootstrap 12 column grid

Comment: The code works ok: https://www.bootply.com/zRPACDuz1e, and it's [ok to exceed 12 colums in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/6124/using-clearfix-in-rows-and-cols/28651/why-would-bootstrap-columns-exceed-12-in-a-row#t=201706121251085611055). Post an example and explain specifically what's not working. Also there is no span9 column in Bootstrap 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap grid is split up to ***12 columns***

By having 4 `col-md-6` divs in a row it means you have 24 columns which is not accepted.
You need to use 2 `row`'s:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="span9">
        <div class="well np">
            <div class="row">
    
                    <div class="col-md-6">Text 1</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">Text 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class="col-md-6">Text 3</div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">Text 4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
```

If you are using a small screen each text will appear after each other